# Projected coordinate system

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system

I used projected (Hungarian EOV) orthophoto for segmentation and classification in eCognition (I defined EOV in ecognition as well), the result was exported into shapefile. I opened orthophoto and shapefile in QGIS and ArcGIS, but exported shapefile doesn't overlap with orthophoto even they have the same coordinate system. Can anyone help me to deal with this issue.

Comment: How much meters is the offset?

Comment: @AndreJ sorry for the delayed reply, offset is about 500 meters to the South.

Comment: @Kazuhito, sorry for the delayed response, could you please tell me how to test custom CRS (remove +towgs parameters)?

Comment: A shapefile does not contain the datum shift information, so eCognition does not get it from the file. From my test case, points without datum shift are about 90m East of the right spot. So it might rather be a somerc issue, or parameter fault. It would spare you a lot of headache if you did the classification in WGS84/UTM instead of HD72/EOV.

Comment: @Kazuhito I tested what you have said, but I got the same result as before.

Comment: @AndreJ Thank you, can you suggest any way to solve this issue?

Comment: @Shukhrat similar to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219533/transforming-projected-coordinate-system, you can reproject the HD72 orthophotos to WGS84/UTM 34N inside QGIS, and hand those over to eCognition.

Comment: @AndreJ I should have read previous discussions linked above, in which datum change had been discussed already. With my apologies, I am highly tempted to remove my comments.